# how to fix indent eslint error in nested styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, styled-components

How to fix this eslint error?

I want to write below format.

```
const Hoge = styled.div`
  ...

  .class {
    color: ${props =>
      props.a !== 'aaaaaa' &&
      props.b !== 'bbbbbb' &&
      '#ccc'};
  }
`
```

But this format has eslint error.

[image]

> error: [eslint] Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6. (indent)

I'd like to know about fix this.

I'm using below versions.

```
"styled-components": "^3.1.6",
"eslint": "^4.17.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
"prettier": "^1.10.2",
"prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1",
```

And eslint setting for indent is just below.

```
 "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
```

Answer (score 3):

First, eslint's [`indent`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) rule is working correctly, see [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8880). If you want to continue to use styled-components and adhere to your linter configurations for `indent` the easiest solution is to probably not write the interpolation function inline, but instead assign it to a variable.

For example:

```
const getColorForClass = ({ a, b }) => {
  return a !== 'aaaaaa' && b !== 'bbbbbb' && '#ccc'
}

const Hoge = styled.div`
  .class {
    color: ${getColorForClass};
  }
`
```

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me to separate it into a function, but it definitely makes the whole thing cleaner even without eslint borking

Answer (score 3):

By adding an exception to the eslint config, I'm able to ignore the relevant blocks so that autofix doesn't trash the identation. You still have to manage it manually but at least it's keeps what you write

In `.eslintrc.js`:

```
const styledComponentArrowFn =
  'TaggedTemplateExpression > TemplateLiteral > ArrowFunctionExpression';

const ignoredNodes = [
  styledComponentArrowFn,
  `${styledComponentArrowFn} > BlockStatement`,
];

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'indent': ['error', 2, {
      ignoredNodes,
    }],
  }
}
```

Reference: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#ignorednodes

Answer (score -1):

I wanna point out this needs to fix some if/case to properly handle success/error case, otherwise you'll end up with

```
.class {
  color:
}
```

So I suggest this approach, and fortunately it solve the eslint issue itself.

```
.class {
  ${props =>
    props.a !== 'aaaaaa' &&
    props.b !== 'bbbbbb' && 'color: #ccc'
  };
}
```